# Expressing a sequence of scripted Python string replacement in Haskell

Tags: haskell, file-io, text-processing, replace

I often use Python to replace various types of characters in text, using scripts that look like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
# coding=UTF-8

import sys

for file in sys.argv[1:]:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
    f = open(file)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
    fs = f.read()
    r1 = fs.replace('\n',' ')
    r2 = r1.replace('\r',' ')                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
    r3 = r2.replace('. ','.\n\n')                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
    r4 = r3.replace('é','e')
    r5 = r4.replace('\xc2',' ')
    r6 = r5.replace('\xa0',' ')
    r7 = r6.replace(' ',' ')
    r8 = r7.replace(' ',' ')
    r9 = r8.replace('\n ','\n')
    f.close()                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
    print r8
```

But I am learning Haskell now, because I am sick of Python.

My best try at doing that in Haskell is

```
#!/usr/bin/runhaskell 

import System.IO

main :: IO ()
main = do 
       inh <- getArgs >>= withFileLines
       outh <- -- ??
       mainloop inh outh
       hClose inh
       hClose outh

replacements :: String -> String
replacements = unwords $ map -- hmm....
```

...and, I have no idea where to go from there.

Comment: Should that be `print r8` or `print r9` at the end? It's probably better if you just change every `rN` (for all *N*) with just plain `r`, so you can't make these kinds of errors.

Comment: Alternatively, you could just do this: `print f.read().replace('\n',' ').replace('\r',' ').replace('. ','.\n\n').replace('é','e').replace('\xc2',' ').replace('\xa0',' ').replace(' ',' ').replace(' ',' ').replace('\n ','\n')`, but there seems to be a lot of busywork in this anyway …

Comment: @Len well, thanks for pointing that out -- actually, all of these replacements are for populating my mp3 player with machine-read audiobooks of public domain texts. as such, the quality of the reading i end up with is more important to me than the code i'm using. but it's still nice to see how to write *good* python.

Comment: Of course, I understand the need to be pragmatic when you really just want to get somewhere. Still, there are various optimisations you can make (to your code, I mean, not to the speed of it) which can make matters easier for you later. Anyways, good luck with the Haskell!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest methods in Haskell involve mapping a `Char -> Char` replacement function (the `f` below) over the input, producing a new output (the `interact` function takes care of the fopen/fclose pattern):

```
main = interact $ map f
      where
        f '\n'   = ' '
        f '\r'   = ' '
        f 'é'    = 'e'
        f '\xa0' = ' '
        f c      = c
```

You can modify this to do your own IO, use the `Text` package etc, but the basic pattern of character transformations is the same.

Comment: This method will perform the replacements in parallel (to the data, not on a separate core), as opposed to the Python version, which performs the replacements serially, so if you replace `'a'` with `'b'` and `'b'` with `'c'`, you end up with `'a'`s being `'c'`s in the Python version, but being `'b'`s in the Haskell version. You can also not perform multi-character replacements like this.

Comment: Sure - this can be extended in many ways: folding `f` over a list of transformations; using text fragments; writing a proper parser ...

Comment: Yes, I was just informing, not criticising :)

Comment: But if replacement isn't 1-to-1 you may use `concatMap`, or `concat . map` by idea still the same

Comment: how would i use this to replace ' n.e. ' with ' northeast '?